# Как дождаться выполнение метода и при этом не заблокировать основной поток? С# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Имеется `ImageButton`, при нажатии на него срабатывает метод

```
imageButton1.Image_button.Clicked += async (a,o) =>
{
    ExitButton.IsVisible = true;
    Frame.IsVisible = true;
                    
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;

    ImageButton image = (ImageButton)a;
    Image imageMaket = new Image { Source = image.Source };

    StackLayoutFromFrame.Children.Add(imageMaket);

    var NewImage =  await Task.Run(() => DowlandFromUrl(imageButton1.url));
    imageMaket.Source = NewImage.Source;

    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
};


Image DowlandFromUrl(string uri)
{
    Image IB =  new  Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(uri)) };

    return IB;
}
```

Почему этот метод `Clicked()` не дожидается выполнение метода `DowlandFromUrl()`,а запускает его в отдельном потоке? Мне нужно, только после полной загрузки `var NewImage` выполнялись

```
imageMaket.Source = NewImage.Source;
activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
```

и при это не заблокировать основной поток.
Или если я все делаю не правильно,подскажите как всё это реализовать правильно.

Спасибо большое за уделённое время!

Comment: `Или если я все делаю не правильно,подскажите как всё это реализовать правильно` - так и есть. Научитесь использовать привязки, почитайте про MVVM подход. Ваш UI должен быть отделен от основной логики, которая в свою очередь может быть хоть асинхронной, хоть нет. Сейчас у вас каша, где вы дергаете UI элементы в коде.

Comment: `Почему этот метод Clicked() не дожидается` метод дожидается создания вашей картинки, он работает как и должен и `await` отрабатывает как надо, но есть нюанс `ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(uri))` выполняется асинхронно от имени интерфейса. То есть загрузка картинки из сети начинается после того как вы выполните вот это `imageMaket.Source = NewImage.Source;`, то есть когда интерфейс захочет показать картинку, а не тогда, когда вы думаете. Ищите другой способ сделать то, что вам нужно.

Comment: [Image.IsLoading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.image.isloading?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Image_IsLoading)